# Doctrine 2: Entity has no field or association named x

Tags: php, exception, doctrine-orm, associations, dql

I've some troubles while using doctrine to do a simple request by DQL.
Can't find any error in my code, so I ask my question here.

Here is the dcotrine query I tried to execute :

```
$em->createQueryBuilder()->select('p')
  ->from('\lib\models\HarvestPage', 'p')
  ->where('(p.start_hp + ?1 <= p.end_hp OR p.end_hp = 0) AND p.label_hp NOT IN (SELECT r.label_hp FROM \lib\models\HarvestRequest r)')
  ->setMaxResults(1)
  ->setParameter(1, $nbPages)
  ->getQuery()
  ->useResultCache(false)
  ->getOneOrNullResult();
```

It throws me this exception :

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 49 near 'start_hp + ?1': Error: Class lib\models\HarvestPage has no field or association named start_hp
```

And last, the HarvestPage entity :

```
namespace lib\models;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="harvest_page")
 */ 
class HarvestPage {
    /** @Id @Column(type="string", length=25) */
    private $label_hp;
    /** @Column(type="string", length=200, nullable=false) */
    private $link_hp;
    /** @Colum(type="smallint", nullable=false) */
    private $start_hp;
    /** @Colum(type="smallint", nullable=false) */
    private $end_hp;
}
```

The table "harvest_page" is correctly created and populated.
I've tried some fixes but without success :

- Desactivate cache
- Try to rename the field

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The metadata has `@Colum` which should be `@Column`